# Trivial Schur multiplier implies projective representations are linear?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a simple non-abelian finite group with a trivial Schur multiplier and $V$ is a finite-dimensional $ \mathbf{F}_3$-vector space. Can one say that every projective representation $$\rho: G \rightarrow Aut_{\mathbf{F}_3}(V) $$ is linear? Since the Schur multiplier is trivial.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over any field $k$ we can talk about $H^2(G, k^{\times})$ which we might call the "Schur multiplier over $k$"; it vanishes iff every projective representation of $G$ over $k$ lifts to a linear representation. The universal coefficient theorem gives a split exact sequence

$$0 \to \text{Ext}^1(H_1(G), k^{\times}) \to H^2(G, k^{\times}) \to \text{Hom}(H_2(G), k^{\times}) \to 0$$

which implies that $H^2(G, k^{\times})$ vanishes iff $\text{Hom}(H_2(G), k^{\times})$ and $\text{Ext}^1(H_1(G), k^{\times})$ vanish. If $G$ is perfect then $H_1(G)$ vanishes so for a perfect group (and in particular a non-abelian simple group) we only need to consider $\text{Hom}(H_2(G), k^{\times})$. If by "Schur multiplier" you mean $H_2(G)$ then the vanishing of $H_2(G)$ implies that $\text{Hom}(H_2(G), k^{\times})$ vanishes and hence $H^2(G, k^{\times})$ vanishes.

It's worth knowing that this argument fails if $H_1(G) \neq 0$.